# Swipe Transition Animation for Webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I´m loading new content for a webview after a right to left swipe gesture. After the gesture is performed the webview loads its new content. How can I make an animation for this webview which displays a "swiping-away" of the webview´s content accordingly to the gesture? So while the user is swiping from right to left the webview should also be moved from right to left. And eventually "fly away". I think some music apps have this where you can load a new track by swiping one away. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can applied swipe animation with single `UIWebView` by following below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerRight;
    recognizerRight.delegate=self;

    recognizerRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
    [recognizerRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:recognizerRight];


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerLeft;
recognizerLeft.delegate=self;
    recognizerLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
    [recognizerLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:recognizerLeft];


}
```

Now applied swipe effect with help of `CATransition`.

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture
{


        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
        [animation setDuration:0.50];
        [animation setTimingFunction:
         [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [webView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];



}
-(void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGesture
{

        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDelegate:self];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        [animation setDuration:0.40];
        [animation setTimingFunction:
         [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [webView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];


}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, pretty neat I think. The only problem is that the "old" content is seen for a short amount of time on the "new" view and then new content of the webview is loaded. Any idea?

Comment: Edit: Ok, I added this as well to clean the content before swipe:
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use two UIWebViews the one that is flying away and one for the new content. To make it fly away you can just use one of the many libraries out there such as [ZLSwipeableView](https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableView).

In parallel, I would use create a new UIWebView on the location of the first. You should probably make it invisible at first and make it's visibility based on the movement of the first view so it gradually appears.

Answer (score 0):

For swipe gesture and load a new content, you can use:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGR;
    swipeGR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft)];
    swipeGR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeGR.delegate = self;
    swipeGR.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [webview addGestureRecognizer:swipeGR];
```

Comment: animation is missing!